# Cada 2 resultados en foreach sumar un dato con php

Tags: php, php5

Buenas Tardes amigos como se encuentran? los molesto para pedirles ayuda, tengo un foreach asociado a una base de datos y quiero que cada 2 resultados agregue un texto que sale desde una variable, como podría hacerlo dentro del foreach?
La idea es que abajo del ultimo cierre de div cada 2 resultados se sume un texto en particular.

Este es el código:

```
    ob_start();
$notasxcategoriasq = getSeccionesHome();
foreach ($notasxcategoriasq as $nc) {
            echo "
                <div class='titulo'>    
                    <h1>$nc->nombrecat</h1>
                </div>
                <div class='row' style='justify-content: center; margin-bottom:70px!important;'>
                ";

    $notasdelacat = getNotasxCategorias($nc->idcat);
    foreach ($notasdelacat as $nxc1) {

        echo "<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-3x engrillo connota'>
                <div class='contnota ovimg'>
                    <h3><a href='nota_$nxc1->permalink' alt='$nxc1->titulo'>$nxc1->titulo</a></h3>
                    <a href='nota_$nxc1->permalink' class='ovimghov iv2' cabecera='$nxc1->cabecera' alt='$nxc1->titulo'><img src='arc/n$nxc1->id/p/$nxc1->phportada' class='img-fluid i100' alt='$nxc1->titulo' /></a>
                </div>
            </div>";

    }
    echo "</div>";
}
$catenoth = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo usando el índice del array y comparando si es par con el operador `módulo (%)`

> `if(($numero % 2) == 0) // Verdadero si el número es par`

```
ob_start();
$notasxcategoriasq = getSeccionesHome();
foreach ($notasxcategoriasq as $index => $nc) {
            echo "
                <div class='titulo'>    
                    <h1>$nc->nombrecat</h1>
                </div>
                <div class='row' style='justify-content: center; margin-bottom:70px!important;'>
                ";

    $notasdelacat = getNotasxCategorias($nc->idcat);
    foreach ($notasdelacat as $nxc1) {

        echo "<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-3x engrillo connota'>
                <div class='contnota ovimg'>
                    <h3><a href='nota_$nxc1->permalink' alt='$nxc1->titulo'>$nxc1->titulo</a></h3>
                    <a href='nota_$nxc1->permalink' class='ovimghov iv2' cabecera='$nxc1->cabecera' alt='$nxc1->titulo'><img src='arc/n$nxc1->id/p/$nxc1->phportada' class='img-fluid i100' alt='$nxc1->titulo' /></a>
                </div>
            </div>";

    }
    echo "</div>";
    if(($index % 2) == 0) {
       // El índice es par
       echo "<div>Texto agregado cuando el índice es múltiplo de 2</div>";
    }
}
$catenoth = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Referencia: [Operadores aritméticos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!

Answer (score 1):

Podría realizar una variable que se cuente y cada 2 veces entre a un if y dentro del if que el contador otra vez sea igual a 0. mas o menos quedaría de la siguiente manera...

```
ob_start();

$cont = 0;

$notasxcategoriasq = getSeccionesHome();
foreach ($notasxcategoriasq as $nc) {
            echo "
                <div class='titulo'>    
                    <h1>$nc->nombrecat</h1>
                </div>
                <div class='row' style='justify-content: center; margin-bottom:70px!important;'>
                ";

    $notasdelacat = getNotasxCategorias($nc->idcat);
    foreach ($notasdelacat as $nxc1) {

        echo "<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-3x engrillo connota'>
                <div class='contnota ovimg'>
                    <h3><a href='nota_$nxc1->permalink' alt='$nxc1->titulo'>$nxc1->titulo</a></h3>
                    <a href='nota_$nxc1->permalink' class='ovimghov iv2' cabecera='$nxc1->cabecera' alt='$nxc1->titulo'><img src='arc/n$nxc1->id/p/$nxc1->phportada' class='img-fluid i100' alt='$nxc1->titulo' /></a>
                </div>
            </div>";



     if($cont == 2){
         echo "<label>Texto...</label>";
        $cont = 0;
     }


    }
    echo "</div>";
    $cont = $cont + 1;
}
$catenoth = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

El contador agregado es el siguiente...

```
$cont = 0;


     if($cont == 2){
        echo "<label>Texto...</label>";
         $cont = 0;
     }
   $cont = $cont + 1;
```

***Espero y te funcione***

Comment: Lo probé no funcionó igual muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la solución más simple sería cambiar el `foreach` a un `for` para que la variable lleve el conteo y con un condicional se resuelva ese caso especial cada 2 resultados. Otra forma de no modificar tanto el código sería agregar un contador.